How to convert a Date to the midday Time in UTC in Ruby-on-Rails, regardless of the timezone?
I have a Date instance in Ruby-on-Rails. I would like to convert it into the midday in Time in UTC.
How can I do it?
I thought this would work.
date = Date.new(2024, 10, 20)
time = date.to_time + Time.now.gmt_offset + 3600*12
  # => 2024-10-20 12:00:00 +0100
time.utc
  # => 2024-10-20 11:00:00 UTC

I think it did work, but it seems it doesn't work anymore; it gives 11 o'clock in UTC as opposed to 12...  Considering the 1-hour difference, I suspect it is related to the fact my machine is in the UK timezone.  But how come?
A lot of past articles and Q&As referred to DateTime in Ruby. However, DateTime has been deprecated in Ruby (see, for example, this article in 2020). So, I would like to get a Time.
What is the (best) way to achieve this in Ruby 3 and Rails 7?

In plain Ruby, you can pass the date values to Time.utc and set the hour explicitly, no need to calculate any timezone offsets:
date = Date.new(2024, 10, 20)

Time.utc(date.year, date.month, date.day, 12)
#=> 2024-10-20 12:00:00 UTC


Rails' (possibly) best way
Straight to the point, the easiest and clearest way to convert a Date to the midday Time in UTC with Rails may be this:
date = Date.new(2024, 10, 20)
date.to_time(:utc) + 12.hours
  # => 2024-10-20 00:00:00 UTC

Here, Date#to_time in Rails optionally accepts an argument of either :local (Default) or :utc (Official Reference), unlike native Ruby.
Note that the default option :local means:

Ruby's process timezone, i.e. ENV['TZ']. If the application's timezone is needed, then use in_time_zone instead.


Why didn't the OP's way work?
Here is an explanation of why your example code did not work; it is because

2024-10-20 was still in the British summer time (BST: +0100) zone
Ruby considers the time zone of the system time, and Ruby's Date#to_time seems to take it into account, where the time-zone actually depends on the date in the regions where they periodically switch between the summer and winter times.
Therefore, 2024-10-20 is converted with Date#to_time into 00:00 on the day in the BST (British Summer Time) timezone. See below:

Date.new(2024,10,20).to_time  # => 2024-10-20 00:00:00 +0100 (BST)
Date.new(2024,10,28).to_time  # => 2024-10-28 00:00:00 +0000 (GMT=UTC)


You likely executed the code after the clock change into the GMT/UTC (it is now 28 October 2024), so Time.now.gmt_offset returns 0.
As a result, the time offset from the UTC in Date.new(2024, 10, 20) is now not correctly considered in your code snippet, while it did when you ran the code during the period of the timezone of the BST.

The quickest fix according to your way is to replace the current time for Time.now.gmt_offset with an actual time on the day:
date = Date.new(2024, 10, 20)
time = date.to_time
(time + time.gmt_offset + 3600*12).utc  # ← use "time" instead of Time.now
  # => 2024-10-20 12:00:00 UTC

  # or similarly, but only in Rails:
(time + time.gmt_offset + 3600*12).in_time_zone("UTC")  # in Rails only
(time + time.gmt_offset + 12.hours).utc                 # in Rails only
  # => 2024-10-20 12:00:00 UTC

Related altenative ways
The following is some altenative ways.
date = Date.new(2024, 10, 20)
t = Time.new(date.year, date.mon, date.day, 12, in: "UTC")
t = Time.new(*(date.strftime("%Y %m %d 12").split.map(&:to_i)), in: "UTC")
t = Time.parse(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 12:00:00 UTC"))
 # => 2024-10-20 12:00:00 UTC

 # Rails only
t = Time.use_zone("UTC") do
      midday = Time.zone.parse(date.to_s)+12.hours
    end
  # => <ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone> Sun, 20 Oct 2024 12:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00

The last one uses two Rails class methods for Time (as suggested in this past answer): Time.use_zone and Time.zone (n.b., slightly confusingly, native Ruby has an instance method Time#zone, which returns a String of the timezone).

Date.new(2024, 10, 20).to_time(:utc).at_middle_of_day
  # => 2024-10-20 12:00:00 UTC

Docs:
Date#to_time,
Time#at_middle_of_day
